# Fan RPM way too high when playing videos, or using webcam

Tags: kernel, cpu, 19.04, fan, overheating

I want to make sure that my machine is behaving normally.

OS = Ubuntu 19.04 64-bit

Laptop = Dell Inspirion 13 7000
**(model number corrected)**

Memory = 7.5 GB

Processor = Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8

It seems to me the fan RPM is too high when comparing with the CPU usage. Whenever I use the webcam, watch a video on chrome the fan goes to as high as 50,000 rpm, but `top -i` reveals that nothing is using a high percentage of CPU or memory.

Is this normal for the fan? I have a feeling that Ubuntu 19.04 may have introduced kernel changes that are no longer compatible with my hardware.

**Is it possible that there are programs running that are not displayed in `top` and are not logging to `journalctl` that are consuming memory/cpu without my knowledge?**

I have also not cleaned any of the fans but the computer is fairly new (under 6 months old)

Here is a screenshot of the activity from `psensor`

[image: 19]

Comment: You could try install `TLP` and see if it helps. Please, take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159995/why-is-ubuntu-mate-16-04-runs-hotter-than-windows-7-on-my-core2-and-ati-mobility/1160001#1160001

Comment: I have installed `TLP` actually, this is the result after using it

Comment: I would say your CPU temperature seems in the normal range. Perhaps it is worth a look into the BIOS options like CPU fan speed options (max, quiet, adaptive ... etc). Also please keep in mind `TLP` takes some time to show some difference up to a few days depending on your usage.

Comment: Dell's support site does not find an Inspiron 12 7000; I wanted to go there to find your hardware manual. Have you cleaned the CPU fan and any other fans inside? Please click [edit] to reply, and please also include your Service Tag number so I can find the Service Manual. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: I would keep your Dell Service Tag private. Non-Dell employees such as us don't need to know it. Source: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Buyer-wants-service-tag-before-purchasing/td-p/3598343

Comment: My Dell based system doesn't have fans come on at all in Linux (full blast with windows 10 gaming though). My CPU's run at 55 degrees though whereas yours are at 48 degrees.

Comment: Can you please add your specs ? what could you possible attribute this to then? Is it possible that there are programs running that are not displayed in `top` and are not logging to `journalctl` that are consuming memory/cpu without my knowledge?