# Is the processor fan not working?

Tags: cpu, fan

Please take a look at my computer's temperatures below:

> coretemp-isa-0000
>
> Adapter: ISA adapter
>
> Package id 0:  +56.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
>
> Core 0:        +56.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
>
> Core 1:        +52.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device

**Processor Fan:    0 RPM**

**CPU:            +55.0°C**

Other:          +47.0°C
Other:          +44.0°C
GPU:            +52.0°C

Are these temperatures normal?

Is the processor fan not working?

How do I control the speed of the fan processor?

Comment: What is the problem? Temerature is OK.

Comment: Quite a few fans are not able to be controlled by us.  Best bet would be to keep computer clean and keep an eye on temps every so often.  Can have psensor or the like running and give alarm if temp get high(80).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1160001/968501

Comment: Suggest you run `sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw && sudo tlp start` so you may have more tools to monitor your fan. Without knowing your model number (from the serial number plate/sticker, please), that's about as much as we can suggest. Please obtain that model number, then click [edit] here and add it to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].