# (Advanced) Ubuntu AMD GPU issue (possible overheating/misconfigured sensors/bad driver)

Tags: drivers, overheating, fan, temperature, amdgpu-pro

This is my first post. I will try to give as much information about the issue as possible. The post turned out to be a little long, but it is quite detailed.

**System specs:**
Processor: i5-4690k
Gpu: MSI R9 290x
Ram: 4 GB DDR3
Storage: 500 GB SSD
Monitor: Benq XL2411

I am using a dual boot with Windows, and I usually play the game on Windows.The game runs at ~144 FPS with no issues whatsoever.

However, recently I thought about using Linux a little more, and decided to install Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the AMDGPU-PRO driver from AMD. I followed the installation instructions thoroughly, and made sure it is installed correctly.

When I started up Dota 2 it worked fine, until I entered a public game, after which I suddenly lost display signal either after the game starts or at some arbitrary time. Sometimes the signal loss duration is 5 minutes into the game, sometimes 20, sometimes 40. When I lose display signal, sound still plays on the background for a few seconds, but it stops or starts looping. My computer is still on, because I can hear the fans and see the LEDs. The power button does not work, unless I hold it down for 5 seconds (hard shutdown). Upon restarting, the game runs perfectly fine if I boot windows. If I boot Ubuntu, it will last for another 5-10 (sometimes more) minutes before the aforementioned sequence of events is repeated.

The issue persists no matter whether I choose to login to Ubuntu Wayland or Xorg, or whether I have processes running in the background.

I decided to check the GPU temperature using `lm-sensors`. I installed it, ran sensor detect, and ran the sensors command. While idle on the desktop, I got the following output:

```
amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:       +1.00 V 
fan1:             N/A  (min =    0 RPM, max =    0 RPM)
edge:         +66.0°C  (crit = +104000.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       36.11 W  (cap = 208.00 W)
```

The first thing I noticed was that the GPU temp kept rising while idle in desktop, by about 1 degree every few minutes. Also `fan1` sensor was not working, for some reason. I ran `sensors -u`, and here is the output:

```
amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:
  in0_input: 1.000
fan1:
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature fan1_input: Can't read
  fan1_min: 0.000
  fan1_max: 0.000
edge:
  temp1_input: 65.000
  temp1_crit: 104000.000
  temp1_crit_hyst: -273.150
power1:
  power1_average: 36.113
  power1_cap: 208.000
```

Then I decided to download a [script from git](https://github.com/DominiLux/amdgpu-pro-fans) that manually sets fanspeed.

Well, I tested it and when I execute it with 100 it does make the fans louder, however I doubt this is really their max, as I've heard them way louder while playing Battlefield 4 on Windows. Then, the `sensors` GPU temp starts lowering while idle on desktop.

Now I tried playing Dota 2 with fans set to 100 and monitoring the GPU temperature through `sensors`. The temperature would rise considerably, reaching about 82-86 degrees in main menu and 95+ in-game. As soon as it reaches above 96-97, the monitor loses signal, as I previously described. The GPU temperature also rises quite rapidly, 1 degree every few minutes or so. It does not happen anymore at the start of the game with fans running at 100, but the result is essentially the same after some time.

I really wanted to make sure that this is not an issue with the hardware, so I used my Radeon settings program to monitor my GPU's performance during a game of Dota 2 on Windows.

The GPU temperature at the main menu was about 74 degrees, in-game it ranged from 85 to 93 at max, staying at 90-88 most of the time, including during teamfights (which should require a lot more GPU power).

The fan speed is about 2400 RPM on average, with about 2550 peak during gameplay. During idle desktop usage it's more like 1200 RPM. I have run Battlefield 3 and 4 on ultra graphics and had no such issues on Windows. Furthermore GPU utilization is about 30% -50% on Dota 2, with CPU utilization being about 70-80%.

The GPU sensors work perfectly well on Windows and are quite accurate, especially with fan speed.

I looked up at what this amdgpu-pro-fans script does, and found that it essentially accesses the card's directory (`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon2`) and gets the value from the file `pwm1_max` (which is `255`), calculates the percentage of the input, and writes this new value down in `pwm1`. I have no idea why this value is `255` or what it represents. There is also a `fan1_enable` file, which contains a value of `1`, and a `fan1_input` file, which cannot be opened, because it is of "unknown type". This is probably related to the issue in `sensors`. Also, the file `temp1_crit` shows `104000000`, while `temp1_crit_hyst` shows `-273150`. I am pretty sure these values are garbage. They can also be seen in the sensor output above.

`hwmon2` is the only folder in `hwmon`. I see some people have `hwmon3`, but I don't know why. Here is a screenshot of the `hwmon2` folder:

[image: screenshot of the hwmon2 folder]

I am not 100% sure that GPU overheating is causing my issue, but I think it is very likely.

I have tried reinstalling the AMDGPU-PRO driver at least 5 times. My system and AMDGPU-PRO driver is up to date.

I am running Dota 2 with the same settings as on Windows.

I am using the Vulkan API in Dota 2. On OpenGL the performance is quite noticeably lower, averaging 80 FPS in-game. On Vulkan it more or less matches my Windows performance.

On a final note, the game's FPS do not really drop before the black screen/loss of signal on my monitor. It happens rather instantaneously. There is no lag or anything like that.

Any ideas on what may be causing the issues?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I saw that you are not familiar with the markdown, I tried to fix your post, I hope I didn't miss anything. Regarding all the `/sys` files, those are not regular files, they are created as interfaces to devices. That's why some of them are read only, or write only. I am not sure if it is exactly like that, but you can think of it as if the driver creates those files and then utilities (like lm-sensors) use them (by reading or writing or both). The numbering depends on the exact hardware and the driver, so minor differences are expected.

Comment: It may be helpful if you can specify the version of the amdgpu driver you are using --probably 19.30 if you have installed it recently. I am using 19.30 with some Radeon RX 5700 and I am having some issues, `sensors` doesn't give me fan control nor the temperature of the graphics card. I think that issue may be related to yours, maybe the linux driver is lacking some hardware control or something like that. I hope somebody can help us!

Comment: FYI, 255 is a typical max value in computers, as 255 can be represented with 8 bits (255 is written `1111 1111` in binary or `FF` in hexadecimal). What that means is that the hardware is using 8 bits to set up the level, thus 0 is the minimum and 255 is the maximum. Sometimes, to be more friendly, you can see that graphical applications tend to convert that to a percentage 0-100, but the "real" granularity levels are the other ones.

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1160001/968501